# How does map decide which value to pick if key is duplicated

Tags: scala

I am trying the following code to learn map collection. I notice that if the 'key' is duplicated, 'map' picks on value. How does the compiler decide which value to pick?

```
//key 2 and 3 are duplicated and has different values
val m3 = Map((2->"1"), (2->"2"), (3->"3"), (3->'4'))
m3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(2 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
```

//why was "2" and '4' picked and not "1" and "3"

Comment: They are created in order. The 2nd one overwrites the 1st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would use the latest insert into the Map (think about it as an equivalent of an UPSERT: update if the key exists or insert into the Map if it does not).